# Sails.js downloading file

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, filesystems, sails.js

I'm beginner in `sails.js` and I need to add some logic to existing server.
I need to retrieve image from shared network, so I added `ImageController.js` and action in it:

```
module.exports = {
    download: function(req, res) {
        var run = req.param('run');
        var test = req.param('test');
        var file = req.param('file');
        var path = util.format('\\\\tch-smain\\Share\\AutoTest\\Screenshots\\%s\\%s\\%s.jpeg', run, test, file);
        fileAdapter.read(path)
            .on('error', function (err){
                return res.serverError(err);
            })
            .pipe(res);
    }
};
```

Then I registered route in `config\routes.js`:

```
'/img': 'ImageController.download'
```

But when I trying to execute `GET /img?run=a&test=b&file=c` I get 500 error **Internal Server Error. Something isn't right here**.
But file on `\\tch-smain\Share\AutoTest\Screenshots\a\b\c.jpeg` exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download files - sails.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608304/how-to-download-files-sails-js)

Comment: What does the `500` error says?

Comment: @khushalbokadey "Internal Server Error. Something isn't right here."